# Ordering results by relevance using Solr search

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search, lucene, solr, sunspot

I'm new to Solr search and trying to get a grasp on how to handle ordering of results. I'm using Ruby on Rails together with the Sunspot gem to interface with Solr.

I have an Article model, that has the following fields that are indexed:

```
text Title
text AuthorNames
integer NumberOfReviews
```

I'd like to be able to perform a search on Solr where:

- Exact title matches are returned before anything else
- Positive weighting is given proportionally to Articles with a larger NumberOfReviews

Ideally, I'd also like to be able to do something like Google where near misses and typos are also found to a certain extent, and alternative searches are suggested when it seems like the user might have made a mistake, though I'm not sure this is possible.

Can anyone help or point me in the right direction? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. "Weighting" is usually called "boosting" in Solr/Lucene jargon.
2. Take a look at [dismax queries](http://www.lucidimagination.com/blog/2010/05/23/whats-a-dismax/) and [its parameters](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DisMaxQParserPlugin), there's a lot of tuning you can do there. For example you can use the bf parameter to boost articles with larger NumberOfReviews.
3. Mistake checking, alternative suggestions: see [SpellCheckComponent](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SpellCheckComponent)